# file not being saved to S3 with paperclip amazon configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, paperclip

I am developing a Rails 3 app that has user upload for there profile picture. I have followed a number of online configurations and I think I am really close to getting it working but I can't seem to get the file to go to the amazon bucket for some reason.

Here is my setup

user model has this

```
has_attached_file :photo, 
                    :styles => {:small => "83x83>"},
                    :storage => :s3,
                    :s3_credentials => "#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/s3.yml",
                    :path => "/:style/:filename",
                    :bucket => 'mybucket'
```

my yml file looks like so

```
development:
  bucket: "dev"
  access_key_id: "kjlkjlkjlkjlkjlkjlkj"
  secret_access_key: "kjlkjlkjlkjlkjlkjlkj/kjlkjlkjlkjlkjlkjlkj"

test:
  bucket: "test"
  access_key_id: "kjlkjlkjlkjlkjlkjlkj"
  secret_access_key: "kjlkjlkjlkjlkjlkjlkj/kjlkjlkjlkjlkjlkjlkj"

production:
  bucket: "prod"
  access_key_id: "kjlkjlkjlkjlkjlkjlkj"
  secret_access_key: "kjlkjlkjlkjlkjlkjlkj/kjlkjlkjlkjlkjlkjlkj"
```

my action in my controller does this

```
def upload_image
     current_user.update_attributes(params[:user])
     redirect_to  "/profile/#{current_user.id}"
  end
```

I am inspected the user.photo object in the rails console and I don't see anything in the :errors param. I am pretty stumped at this point. I did use my FTP program (transmit) to connect to the S3 account using the same creds and it worked just fine so I am pretty sure my config is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Change your configuration to this:

```
has_attached_file :photo, 
                    :styles => {:small => "83x83>"},
                    :storage => :s3,
                    :s3_credentials => YAML.load_file("#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/s3.yml"),
                    :path => "/:style/:filename",
                    :bucket => 'mybucket'
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `User` model you call

```
:bucket => 'mybucket'
```

But in your `yml` file, none of the buckets are called `mybucket`.  Try making sure the names match.